# "/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca failed" error when trying to print from a Canon MF8030cn

Tags: 12.04, printing, canon

I have not been able to get my MF8030cn printer working on ubuntu 12.04. 64bit
I have Googled for days and tried every tip I could find, including a long thread on the ubuntu forums, but no luck.

The error message is `/usr/lib/cups/filter/pstoufr2cpca failed`

Any ideas?

Comment: it seems the ubuntu problem with your printer.
dont you try to test your printer at another version of ubuntu ?

Comment: It works on older 32bit versions, but I would really like to stay with the latest Ubuntu as I have been using Ubuntu for many years now. However if there is no other way :(

Comment: there is a rpm for 64bit distros and I've tried alien and so on, but to no effect. I'm actually seriously considering Fedora right now because of this as I have used it in the past, but I really would like to stay with ubuntu - doesn't anyone have an idea of some troubleshooting I could try out. It was an expensive printer/scanner so it's kind of a showstopper for me I'm afraid - any help would really be welcome :)

Comment: Could you post more lines from the logs? Like, If you have referred syslog, try locating anything strange in other logs at the same timespan.

Comment: Check [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1723101&page=2) thread. Might be helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A native 64-bit driver package is now available!

- The only real solution is to install the native 64-bit drivers, but unfortunately Canon only provides 32-bit DEB packages.
- After a lot of experimentation and a borrowed Canon MF4350dn all-in-one, I've managed to build the drivers *and* get them to work. They are available [in a PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eauanswers/+archive/canon64/).

#### How to install:

- **Important:** you must first install the `libxml2:i386` package (which pulls in the 32-bit libc6 and zlib packages which are also needed). This manual step is necessary because the alternative is to force people to install the 250 MB+ `ia32-libs` package.
- Start by opening a terminal and typing:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libxml2:i386
  ```
- Add the PPA with:

  ```
  sudo apt-add-repository ppa:auanswers/canon64
  ```
- Update with `sudo apt-get update`
- Install the North American version:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cndrvcups-ufr2-us
  ```

  or the European version

  ```
  sudo apt-get install cndrvcups-ufr2-uk
  ```
- Make sure your printer's device in *Settings...Printing* is the `cnusb:` device:

  [image]

  [image]

---

**Help! I got a warning, installation failed, now what!?**

[image]

This just means you forgot to install the i386 dependencies. Type `sudo apt-get install libc:i386 zlib1g:i386 libxml2:i386`, and then try again with `sudo apt-get install cndrvcups-ufr2-us` (or `-uk`)

Comment: Cool work! can you update the packages?

Comment: `# apt-get install libxml2:i386` says `E: Unable to locate package libxml2:i386` on neon which is ubuntu based. Source list says `deb http://archive.neon.kde.org/user focal main`, I guess one needs to add something?

Comment: Well, OK, nevermind, the canon website has linux 64 bit drivers these days.